# Java Spring - Disable any logging sent to server.log in Wildfly 11

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logging, wildfly

I have a java spring REST web service. This webservice interacts with a database, and I had configured the logging with the Wildfly console, to send error messages and everything about this war into a myapp.log file.

I have this kind of errors sent to myapp.log file (which is expected):

```
22:28:09.027 [default task-1] [org.myapp.testapp] ERROR p.c.p.h.controller.TestController- ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_constraint"
```

Using in my java code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

...

 static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);
```

and sending the error after a exception. As I said, I get this kind of error messages in my myapp.log file, but also I get the equivalent error in server.log:

```
 22:52:08,507 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
 22:52:08,508 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_constraint"
Detail: Key (myvalue)=(Avalue) already exists.
```

How can I configure my java project to disable those messages to server.log? I want that myapp.log be the only log file for my application

Comment: How do you have logging for your application configured? How is the `myapp.log` file configured?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I have my file configured in the file src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml in my project, this is the file definition: <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${jboss.server.log.dir}/myapp.log</file>
        <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [org.myapp.testapp] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

Comment: You can't really redirect the messages from Hibernate to your own log file since they are system level components.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the proper logger for that class (org.hibernate) in your log4j.properties file and emit them or forward them appropriately to corresponding appender

Comment: If you search for per deployment logging, you will see how to make sure that logs from your app go to their own logging rather than using server.log